# Existence of a unique set of sequences in a given set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Problem:** Let $A$ be an arbitrary nonempty set. Prove the existence of a unique set $B$ for which holds the equivalence $\forall x(x\in B\iff \exists n(n \in \omega \land x:n\to A))$

**Comment:** I'm trying to prove the existence and uniqueness(only one) of such sets. This is the set denoted by $Seq(A)$ and it's actually the set of all finite sequeneces in $A$. I'm again stuck with my attempts on how to prove this statement.

Any comments, ideas and suggestions would be very much welcome! 
As usual, thank you in advance!

*All terminology is related to Set theory.

Comment: Can you find a bigger set that $B$ must be a subset of and construct $B$ via specification?

Comment: Uniqueness follows pretty easily form extensionality. Do you see why?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Not at all! I was considering whether B could be represented by a function. Also wondering if there would be any complications in the case when A is infinite set, actually it's generalization so A should be regarded as infinite set, I guess.

Comment: @e2l3n: Whenever $\varphi(x)$ is a formula that doesn't mention $B$ (but may mention other parameters), then there is at most one $B$ such that $\forall x(x\in B\iff \varphi(x))$ -- namely the set of all things $x$ that $\varphi(x)$ holds for. Two _different_ $B$s that both had this property would contain exactly the same elements, at which point extensionality says the are the same set.

Comment: Define the set $w$.

Comment: @DanChristensen: I'm pretty sure he was trying to write $\omega$. (But even if he isn't, it doesn't matter -- as long as it's a set things will work out).

Comment: @DanChristensen $w$ is the least infinite ordinal.

Comment: @e2l3n: That's not usually called $w$ but $\omega$ (Greek letter small omega). In TeX, `$\omega$` produces $\omega$.

Comment: @user45150 what would the benefit be by doing so?

Comment: @e2l3n: It would be one way to prove existence. (We're assuming that solving the problem counts as a "benefit" for you ...) If you have a different way in mind, let us hear it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Henning, thank you for the explanation. I understand the idea and agree. Correct me if I'm wrong but this only proves that the set is unique.

Comment: @user45150 Do you mean another ordinal?

Comment: @e2l3n: My first comment was for uniqueness. User45150's hint is for existence.

Comment: I understand the general idea. if I find a set containing B, B is obviously a set of functions, then using the Axiom schema of specification would prove the statement. However what that set containing B might be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21247/discussion-between-e2l3n-and-henning-makholm).

Comment: Well, every _element_ of $B$ is a subset of $\omega\times A$ and therefore an element of `_____`, so $B$ itself is a subset of ...?